# ServletContext and Session object

Tags: java, servlets

Is the ServletContext and Session object which we get from request object (HttpServletRequest) behave the same ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sessions are user specific.

Servlet contexts are essentially global (within the context of that servlet), meaning all users who hit that servlet will share the same servlet context.