# Difference between session.getAttribute("someString") vs session.getServletContext().getAttribute("someString")

Tags: java, servlets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ServletContext and Session object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076389/servletcontext-and-session-object)

I am finding it strange that

```
session.getAttribute("someString");
```

works while

```
session.getServletContext().getAttribute("someString");
```

does not **always** work.

I am adding objects to session by getting HttpSession object from HttpServletRequest request with

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("someString")
```

Comment: Get a `SCWCD` book go through it.

Comment: @AmitD what does your knowledge from SCWCD suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple: [the session](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) is not the same thing as [the servlet context](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html). They are quite different concepts, and have different uses.

[Cletus sums it up nicely:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076400/139010)

> Sessions are user specific.
>
> Servlet contexts are essentially global (within the context of that servlet), meaning all users who hit that servlet will share the same servlet context.

Comment: You're right. I am actually getting the servletContext instead of session.